# How can I get a "flatter" URL in Wagtail?

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a `DestinationIndexPage` model which sits directly within the root page, within this are multiple `DestinationPage` instances.

They can be accessed with URLs like this:

- */destinations/london*
- */destinations/birmingham*
- */destinations/manchester*

Is there a way to keep the destination pages within the `DestinationIndexPage` but have them served from the following URLs?

- */london*
- */birmingham*
- */manchester*

This is to keep the Wagtail admin organised, but also prevent deeply nested URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I will only ever have one child `page` hidden, I've created a couple of mixins to "conceal" a page. Take the following hierarchy:

```
HomePage --> Destination Index --> Destinations
```

`HomePage` would have this mixin:

```py
class ConcealedChildMixin(Page):
    """
    A mixin to provide functionality for a child page to conceal it's
    own URL, e.g. `/birmingham` instead of `/destination/birmingham`.
    """

    concealed_child = models.ForeignKey(
        Page,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='concealed_parent',
        help_text="Allow one child the ability to conceal it's own URL.",
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('concealed_child')
    ]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def route(self, request, path_components):
        try:
            return super().route(request, path_components)
        except Http404:
            if path_components:
                subpage = self.specific.concealed_child

                if subpage and subpage.live:
                    return subpage.specific.route(
                        request, path_components
                    )

            raise Http404
```

And `Destinations` would have this mixin:

```py
class ConcealedURLMixin:
    """
    A mixin to provide functionality for a page to generate the correct
    URLs if it's parent is concealed.
    """

    def set_url_path(self, parent):
        """
        Overridden to remove the concealed page from the URL.
        """
        if parent.concealed_parent.exists():
            self.url_path = (
                '/'.join(
                    [parent.url_path[: len(parent.slug) - 2], self.slug]
                )
                + '/'
            )
        else:
            self.url_path = super().set_url_path(parent)

        return self.url_path
```